# How To Make the Recipe only to appear below the Category it belong to using ng-repeat in AngularJs?

Tags: html, angularjs, json, spring

Below are the outcome that from postman and part of my html code. Now the problem is, the recipe was not listed in their own Category they belong to when i try to use ng-repeat to list out. How i need to change my html code to make it work? [fail html output, please have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3s90.png)

```
<p ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
   <input type="button" ng-model="category.cID" name="name" ng-value="{{category.cID}}"/>{{category.categoryTitle}}
  <div ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
 <div ng-repeat="recipe in category.recipes" ng-model="recipe.rID"> {{recipe.recipeTitle}}</div></div>
  </p>

[
{
    "cID": 1,
    "categoryTitle": "Main Dishes",
    "recipes": [
        {
            "rID": 1,
            "cookTime": 30,
            "description": "a delicious fried chicken",
            "recipeTitle": "Fried Chicken"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "cID": 2,
    "categoryTitle": "Desert",
    "recipes": [
        {
            "rID": 2,
            "cookTime": 40,
            "description": "a delicious apple pie",
            "recipeTitle": "Apple Pie"

        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: add  plunkr with your code... so that we can understand it better

Comment: `<div>` is invalid child of `<p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working in this [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEpaTqykPC9AvqeaH5lm?p=preview) please check this below code as there is a change of `<p>` tag into `<div>` tag.

**Template:**

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categoryList">
    <input type="button" ng-model="category.cID" name="name" ng-value="category.cID" />
    {{category.categoryTitle}}
    <div ng-repeat="recipe in category.recipes">
      {{recipe.recipeTitle}}
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.categoryList = [{
    "cID": 1,
    "categoryTitle": "Main Dishes",
    "recipes": [{
      "rID": 1,
      "cookTime": 30,
      "description": "a delicious fried chicken",
      "recipeTitle": "Fried Chicken"
    }]
  },
  {
    "cID": 2,
    "categoryTitle": "Desert",
    "recipes": [{
      "rID": 2,
      "cookTime": 40,
      "description": "a delicious apple pie",
      "recipeTitle": "Apple Pie"
    }]
  }];
```

Comment: but how to make the output as "fried chicken" is shown at below of Main dishes and "Apple pie" is shown at below of "Desert?

Comment: That's how this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEpaTqykPC9AvqeaH5lm?p=preview) works as you expect. Please check the link for working example..

Comment: wow!! thx!! One more question, is that possible to do if I click the "main dishes" button, it will appear the the recipe belong to it with using the data above? Can teach me how to do that?

Comment: Of-course we can! I have updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEpaTqykPC9AvqeaH5lm?p=preview) to reflect your requested changes. Just have a look at the same link now. I have just added **ng-show** directive into the second **div** with the dynamic object property **show** to control the div visibility on button click.

Comment: wow!! Amazing!! thx a lot for you help! really learn a lot from this. Thank you so much!!